# How to reset WP page url with deleting the variables

Tags: url-rewriting

In my unsubscribe script there is this command:

http://www.domain.nl/email-acties/?email=info@domain.nl

after the unsubscribe I like to change the url into

http://www.domain.nl/email-acties/

But WordPress does not accept again header().
Also try

```
echo esc_url( remove_query_arg( 'email' ) );
```

That works but does not rewrite the url.

Question:

How can I rewrite the url as written above

Comment: Because you are trying to redirect too late. "Headers already sent" basically means the browser has started to receive the body of the HTTP response. Whatever hook you're using for your unsubscribe, you need to change it to one that runs early like `init` or `template_redirect`

Comment: I have moved the get_header(); lower in the code. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create an if statement to check if the email arg was passed, if so, redirect to the URL without the email. Something like:

```
if ($_GET['email']) {
  //do unsubscribe stuff
  wp_redirect('http://www.domain.nl/email-acties/');
  exit;
}
```

Unsubscribed!

Comment: Hi, I get a failure. 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/deb96951n2/domains/domain.nl/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php:4587) in /home/deb96951n2/domains/domain.nl/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1171

Comment: Because you're running your code too late - see my comment on your original question.

Comment: I have moved the get_header(); lower in the code. Now it works fine. Thanks both!